# Create an elasticsearch index with different query and index time analyzers

Tags: elasticsearch

Although documented, there is no working example of how to create an index with an index time and a different query time analyzer.

I wish to apply a synonym filter on search only. I can test the analyzer if I specify the analyzer name, but without the name, it doesn't detect the default.

What could be wrong?

```
"settings": {
      "index": {        
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "synonym": {
              "type": "synonym",
              "synonyms": [
                "testword => otherword"
              ]
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "default_search": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding",
                "synonym"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "default_index": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          }
        }
```

Note the two different analyzers, named `default_search` and `default_index`. According to the docs, these should be picked up as defaults. So if I execute a search for 'testword' it'll instead search 'otherword'.

I can confirm the default analyzer names are set on the index types:

```
"myIndex": {
    "mappings": {
      "myType": {
        "index_analyzer": "default_index",
        "search_analyzer": "default_search",
        "properties": ...
```

I execute a test search:

Calling without specifying analyzer `/myIndex/_analyze/?pretty=true&text=testword` (expecting it to pickup `default_search` as configured)

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "testword",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 9,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

Calling with specific analyzer `myIndex/_analyze/?analyzer=default_search&pretty=true&text=testword`

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "otherword",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 9,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

An example search, the index contains one item with a fieldvalue of 'otherword'. The query below returns no results, searching for 'otherword' returns the desired item.
`POST myIndex/_search`

```
"query": {
  "multi_match": {
    "query": "testword",
    "analyzer": "default_search",
    "fields": [
      "name"      
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that the default analyzer for indexing should be named `default`, not `default_index` (see [here]).(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/analysis-analyzers.html#default-analyzers). Also can you explain how you've run your test search?

Comment: @Val See updated question showing query

Comment: what version of ES you are using?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 I am using the hosted version from bonsai.io - seems to be version `1.7.2`

Comment: Tried using version `2.2.0` via docker and experiencing the same problem. I'm certain I'm doing something wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're calling the `_analyze` endpoint, that's not a search. You're actually making a request to ES and asking it to analyze the token stream you give it **as if ES was indexing** those tokens, so the default **indexing** analyzer kicks in.

If you want to try the `default_search` analyzer you need to send a request to the `_search` endpoint.

You need to index a document with `otherword` and then search using `/_search?q=testword` and you'll see the `default_search` analyzer kick in.

**UPDATE**

You're not defining the default analyzers properly, i.e. you need to do it in the `settings` (not in `mappings`) and name them properly (i.e. `default` instead of `default_index`).

Here is the index I used for testing:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/myindex -d '{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "testword => otherword"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "default_search": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding",
              "synonym"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          },
          "default": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "myType": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Here is a sample document I have indexed for testing:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/myindex/myType/1 -d '{
  "name": "otherword"
}'
```

Then using the following query without specifying any analyzers, I can find the above document:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex/myType/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "testword",
      "fields": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Response:

```
{
...
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.30685282,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "myindex",
      "_type" : "myType",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 0.30685282,
      "_source":{"name":"otherword"}
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @Val. I didn't forsee the `_analyze` endpoint using the index default rather than search. Unfortunately, even in query, the search default doesn't kick in, even if I specify it. I think I'll have to move the synonym logic to application and process the words prior to the query since Elastic seems to have issues picking it up. I've updated the question to show the sample query.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Val. I tried again from scratch and it works. In pasting my sample code in I had changed the real values to example values for clarity. What I didn't mention is that my 'otherword' is actually 'N°5'.  This value is getting removed by the asciifolding filter I believe. So even  though the synonym is working, the new value has already been removed form the index anyway, thus not matching results. I'm attempting to use a stop word. Thanks again.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!!